# uml sequence diagram - modelling generic behaviour that is applied to operations

Tags: uml

I have a sequence diagram where a client makes an initial call to set up a session. After that initial call, every subsequent operation (e.g. call X, call Y, call Z) called on the server is checked to see if the session exists.  Is there a way to describe this behaviour generically without having to show it for each and every call?  I guess one option is to add a note, but there may be a better way?

[image: session sequence diagram]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Sequence diagram is to show a particular execution (Client and Server should be :Client and :Server in the diagram) it is difficult to introduce factorization. You could use an InteractionUse to reuse a sequence fragment but in this case it will not help since you have only one message ("check session").

Don't forget that diagrams are views of the systems and particularly sequence diagrams are view of a particular transaction. You don't have to show everything in the diagram. You need not show the "check session" messages in this diagram and use another one to show that a server always checks the session, maybe with a state diagram.

Comment: Exactly. Sequence diagrams are not there to formally specify a system (state machines, for instance, are much better suited for that). They are there to *communicate* a typical scenario to another person. In my opinion, a simple sequence diagram is of much more use than a 'complete' one. You can leave out whatever information you want. In this particular case, I would just add in text: "note that the server checks the session upon every method invocation".

Answer (score 2):

On all sequence diagrams, I include preconditions, summary, and postconditions in a single diagram note.  This prevents lots of confusion and follow-up questions from reviewers.  Preconditions include any required initialization and execution.  In this case, a precondition could be "setup session scenario has run".